# Query not working for me

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

I am using angularJs ng-resource.I have tried this

```
angular.module('app.services', ['ngResource'])


   .factory('AngularIssues', function($resource){
         return $resource('../test.json',{},{
         query: {
                    isArray: true,
                    method:'GET'
                }}
       )
   })
```

I have test.json file as below

```
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now in index.html I have written something like this

```
<div ng-controller="editor">
    <button ng-click='get_rest()'>Get element through rest</button>  <br/>
</div>
<div id="message" />
```

My controller is like this

```
  angular.module('app.controllers', [])
      .controller('editor', ['$scope' ,'AngularIssues', function($scope , AngularIssues ) {
        $scope.get_rest = function(){
            $('#message').text(AngularIssues.query());
        }
      }]);
```

I want to see use the get query using ng-resource feature but when I run this on my localhost I did not get anything on clicking the button .Is there any way to achieve this .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: is your AngularIssues.query() returning something?

Comment: No,It is not working (Also I am checking it through $('#message').text(AngularIssues.query()); But It is giving nothing . Is there any other way to check it?).

Comment: you can do a console.log(AngularIssues.query()); and check in the browser console first

Comment: I just want to use some mock up values so that I can integerate it later with REST WEB API Url's That's why I am using .json file.Please suggest me a way to do so.

Comment: V31 , It is not working .My AngularIssues.query() is returning nothing.

Comment: can you create a plunker for same

Comment: Does `../test.json` return anything when typed in your browser?

Answer (score 0):

This won't work. Try to use the normal variable assignment with `{{ result }}` in your markup. `$resource` returns a `$q` object which will be resolved once a result from the query arrives.

In your controller add `$scope.result = AngularIssues.query()` and modify the html markup accordingly.

Comment: ../test.json is not opening in my browser,actually I am using it using php -S localhost:8090/editor.html and my folder structure is something like this

Comment: -editor.html and other folder js containing controller.js and test.json

Comment: I don't know what you're referring to. Try to use `curl` or your browser to return the data first and then make the modifications I suggested. I beliebe there is more than 1 problem with your code/system setup.

Comment: Yes,Actually I think there might be some problem with the setup .I have started with very basic.Can you please tell me a way to create a dropdown field with data which comes through a query(get) for data.json file .that will sort my problem .Thanks for your quick responses

Comment: I don't see how this is related to your initial question. Please start a new thread for new questions!